# Запуск обновления Windows которая стоит на VirtualBox oracle

Tags: virtualbox

Здравствуйте, подскажите как запустить поиск и обновление через командную строку Windows, которая стоит на VirtualBox.
Пробовал так

```
net stop wuauserv
net stop bits
rd /s /q %windir%\softwaredistribution
net start bits
net start wuauserv
wuauclt.exe /detectnow
```

На основной машине работает, на виртуалке — нет.

Comment: 1. Какая версия Windows? 2. Как настроена сеть в VirtualBox и настроена ли?

Comment: Windows 7 ,сеть не настроена

Comment: Так как тогда виртуальная машина будет искать обновления, если там нет сети? Вытащите из хостовой машины сетевой кабель - так и она работать перестанет.

Если у вас на хостовой машине работает, а на виртуалке - нет, то единственное, что приходит на ум на первый взгляд - это как раз параметры сети, для начала.